# How does the new iPad's (aka iPad 3) resolution play with responsive design?

Tags: css, responsive-webdesign, media-queries

So "the new iPad" has been released with a new "retina display" resolution of 2048x1536 px, but the screen size is still 9.7 inches as the previous iPad... I am wondering how will CSS media queries respond to this device?

How will we design a tablet version (i.e. for browser viewports <768px) if the browser reads 1536px width?

Comment: You'll have to use something other than browser width to identify if the browser is on a tablet.

Comment: interesting code posted [in quora](http://www.quora.com/iPad-3rd-gen/How-does-the-new-iPads-resolution-play-with-responsive-design/answer/David-Ross-9?__snids__=36266140#ans1065845)

Answer (score 5):

The iPad3 will almost certainly report its pixel width to be the same as previous iPads. When the iPhone added the retina display, it still heeded CSS for viewports under 480 pixels and so responsive design was unchanged.